# Is there a command-line tool that can read from a file and write the file's contents to stdout, blocking on EOF?

Tags: linux, command-line, tail

Is there anything like `tail –f` that also works well with binary files and supports exit conditions like "on pid X death" or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISTM that `tail –f` works with binary files.  Is there any particular requirement you have that you believe `tail` won’t satisfy?

The original philosophy on Unix was to keep things simple.  While its commercialization may have taken it away from that principle, I wouldn’t expect to find a single program that did file I/O and also monitored the health of other processes.  The best way to get the exit conditions you want may be to write a shell script and wrap it around `tail –f`.

Comment: Indeed, combined with `--pid=` will accomplish the task quite well.

Comment: Hmm, right, unix philosophy. I should keep that in my mind a bit more.